# How to use trackbar in text to speech for progress of reading c#

Tags: c#, .net, text-to-speech

I am writing an application to convert text of file to speech in C# windows forms application. However I would like to add a functionality of progress-bar or track-bar so that it can work like media player for the speech functionality. Using track-bar user can move forward and backward while text file is being read similar to listing of music.

Can anyone help or suggest me as to how to implement?

Comment: The "Text to speech" process shall be executed in a secondary thread. For the progress, this secondary thread may update a progress value V that may be used by a timer of the main window so as to update the track-bar. If the user moves the Track-bar, update a restart value R that will be used by the secondary thread.

Comment: @Graffito, Thank you for replying. But do you have any code snippet which will help me achieve this?